# MongoDb - Modeling storage of users & post in a webapp

Tags: mongodb, uml, nosql

I'm quite new to `nosql` world.

If I have a very simple `webapp` with `users` authenticating & publishing `posts`, what's the `mongodb(nosql)` way to store users & posts on the `nosql db`?

Do I have (like in `relationnal databases`) to store users & posts each one in his own collection? Or store them in the same collection, on different `documents`? Or, finally with a redondant user infos (credentials) on each post he has published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way you could do it is to use two collection, a posts collection and a authors collection. They could look like the following:

**Posts**

```
{
  title: "Post title",
  body: "Content of the post",
  author: "author_id",
  date: "...",
  comments: [
    {
      name: "name of the commenter",
      email: "...",
      comment: "..."
    }],
  tags: [
    "tag1", "tag2, "tag3
  ]
}
```

**Authors**

```
{
  "_id": "author_id",
  "password": "..."
}
```

Of course, you can put it in a single collection, but @jcrade mentioned a reason why you would/should use two collections. Remember, that's NoSQL. You should design your database from an application point of you, that means ask yourself what data is consumed and how.

Comment: If I put all the data in the same collection, I'll have to update all the `posts` when I modify one `user's` username for example.

Comment: Simple answer: Yes, you have to update the appropriate documents, but that's not uncommon in a NoSQL environment. If your user data changes frequently it's a reason for a second collection.

Comment: If the `users` collection have two relations with two other collections (`posts` & another collection). Should I in this case, use the same model, with `user_id` appearing in the two other collections? Can `users` collection have a `foreign key` in the `posts` collection & be `denormalized` with a third collection?

Comment: Of course, you can do something similar like I have done it with the **posts** collection. There's not really the concept of a foreign key in the NoSQL world. Try to forget most of the stuff you have learned in the relational world. As a reminder, don't try to spread your data over to many collections (this can be bad for query Performance).

Comment: Hi @Horizon_Net. This is the pattern suggested by MongoDB too. So thanks for that. Quick question. If there are thousands and thousands of posts by an author, then should we index it somehow or just leave it like that and let the DB do the searching when querying for posts by that author?

Answer (score 2):

This post says it all:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

It really depends on your application, and how many posts you expect your users to have: if it's a one-to-few relationship, then probably using embedded documents (inside your users model) is the way to go. If it's one to many (up to a couple of thousands) then just embed an array of IDs in your users model. If it's more than that, then use the answer provided by Horizon_Net.

Read the post, and you get a pretty good idea of what you will have to do. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you are modeling nosql database you should think in 3 basic ideas

**Desnormalization**

Copy same data on multiple documents. in order to simplify/optimize query processing or to fit the user’s data into a particular data model

**Aggregation**

Embed data into documents for example (blog post and coments) in order to impact updates both in performance and consistency because mongo has one document consistency  at time

**Application level Joins**

Create applicaciton level joins when its not good idea to agregate information (for example each post as idependent document will be really bad because we need to accces to the same resource)

**to answer your question** 
Create two document one is blogPost with all the comments, and tags on it and user ui. Second User with all user information.

Comment: You mean that `post` & `user` share the same `collection`. And, I need to add a `user_id` field on the `post` documents?

Comment: yes but for example if you need to show user name on any post you can added it to blogPost. (this is desnormalization). the reason I have not recomend add all user info to each post its because there is maybe some changing information on user that will decrease the performance. NoSql does not have a standart way it always depend of what are you doing

Comment: But what if I have a big mass of `posts` on this collections, doesnt it slow the search for a certain `user` ( even if the number of `users` is small)?

Comment: yeah this is the reason to keep "main" user information on User collection but you can put the information that you need on each post on blogPost collection too. For example name field not to search in this collection but to show post creator name otherwise you will nedd to query both documents